# SpeechKit does not support architecture x86_64?

Tags: ios

I am using Xcode 6.4, and I have a IOS 8.4 app with SpeechKit framework. It can run successfully on iPad 2, iPad Retina, iPhone 4S and iPhone 5 simulator. But for other simulators(iPad Air, iPhone 5S, iPhone 6Plus, iPhone 6, Resizable iPad, Resizable iPhone), I got the following errors when compile:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKEarcon" 
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKRecognizer"
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKVocalizer"
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SpeechKit"
  "_SKSearchRecognizerType"
```

So anyone has idea on how to solve this problem?

Also, I have added a lot frameworks that SpeechKit might depends on:

```
SpeechKit.framework
AudioToolBox.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Foundation.framework
UIKit.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
AVFoundation.framework
Security.framework
CFNetwork.framework
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's because I did not use the latest version of SpeechKit. Just use the latest one, and they support 64bit architecture now.